# Fleek.co image upload not generating hash and hashV0

Tags: javascript, ipfs, js-ipfs

I was uploading an image using the safari browser, it does not return any ipfs hash.

[image: iamge upload using fleek.co]

[image]

While on the other hand, it returns the ipfs hash if I am using a desktop web browser.

Can anyone help me with this, or at least explain the process?

[image]

Comment: It returns a publicUrl which you can access directly the URL address.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: we noticed you’re using iOS simulator. Based on that, we released 1.0.4 version for @fleekhq/fleek-storage-js that adds a fallback for case sensitive headers https://github.com/FleekHQ/fleek-storage-js/pull/6. Can you try this version to see if it works for you?

Please note that this service is based on Minio and the current authentication is only setup for calls from a server (not a browser for example). This is because it uses API secrets and we don't want to expose them in the browser. Having said that, will take a look at why our Minio fork is not sending the header in those cases (it just hasn't been a priority to replicate because it is not advised to use from browser like that).